# automatically retrieving type of a variable for use in template doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have

```
template<typename T> inline constexpr int sgn(T number) {
  return (T(0) < number) - (number < T(0));
}
int fullNumber = 42;
int fullNumberSign;
float realNumber = 9.75;
int realNumberSign;
```

and I want something like

```
fullNumberSign = sgn<typeid(fullNumber)>(fullNumber);
realNumberSign = sgn<typeid(realNumber )>(realNumber );
```

, which causes the following compiler error in Visual Studio 2017, using C++2x:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "sgn" matches the argument list    Fractions`

My gut tells me that there should be some way to automatically, statically retrieve the type of a variable at compile time, for use in the template. Is there any?

Comment: Does `fullNumberSign = sgn(fullNumber)` not work?

Comment: @StephenNewell That did the trick :)

Comment: *"retrieve the type of a variable at compile time"* - you're looking for `decltype` instead of `typeid`, but yeah you don't need it here because it is deduced.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks anyways, good to know that these are two different things.